# Is it safe to put hdd below motherboard on metal?

Tags: hard-drive

I am currently building a custom pc. I ordered parts and power supply is to big to fit in. It would fit if I remove the HDD stands. So I am asking if it is safe to place the HDD directly on metal, if I removed the HDD stands?

[image: is safe to put hdd here?]

Comment: Probably OK, but I'd raise it off the shelf a bit, perhaps 1 cm, to allow air to circulate and dampen vibration from the case to the HDD and vice versa. Perhaps use strong hook-and-loop tape ('Velcro') along *part* of each edge, and add a spacer (e.g., back-to back tape) to raise it a bit more.

Comment: Extending what @DrMoishePippik says .. I have had HDDs duct taped to a box, duct taped to the case.  I have had them sitting right on the floor of the case without being secured in any way.  These ghetto configurations never failed me for years and years even though they are not optimal.  I don't think it is a sensitive as you are worried about.  Just make sure they can get some air.. and even that isn't probably going to cause a problem.

Comment: It wouldn't make any difference to the drive as long as it's secured well so that moving the PC and tipping it on its side don't let the drive move at all. Having the drive make metal to metal contact with the case is safer for the drive if something goes catastrophically wrong with the ground line in the drive power cable; Like melting cables or shorting something.

Comment: "*So I am asking if it is safe ...*" -- Define "*safe*".  If you can use the HDD to boot the system, but then the HDD fails prematurely after a year or two, was that "*safe*"?  Shock, vibration, and heat are what cause HDD failures.  How are you going to mitigate those conditions?

Answer (score 1):

### Put it in one of the external bays

It is concerning that the power supply does not fit the chassis.  Also the hard drive should not rest in the bottom of the case.  But, if you have a free 5.25" that are usually used for DVD-ROM drive etc, you could use a 3.5inch SSD HDD to 5.25 Bay Adapter.

**Example 1**

[image: 3.5inch SSD HDD to 5.25 Bay Adapter]

**Example 2**
This has vibration dampers

[image: Shock-Proof 3.5" Hard Disk to 5.25" DVD ROM Bay Mounting adapter]

---

Or even a Tray-less Mobile Rack for 3.5-Inch HD (hot swapable) like this:

**Before Drive**
[image]

**With Drive Installed**

[image]

---

This one supports One SSD and 1 HDD at the same time

[image]

[image]

Comment: This would be a great suggestion if that case actually had an external bay ;)

Comment: Good point.  Guess it's gonna be duck tape instead of just getting the right ps.  Should probably get multi-colored so that it looks fly with the mood lighting and plexiglass cover :-)   Brita liquid cooling anyone?